# Identifying a pattern in an array

Tags: recurrence-relations, computability, recursive-algorithms, pattern-recognition

Is there a way to identifying a pattern and/or recursive function for an array?

If yes, how can I do this. Could anyone please help me with some information and/or resource for this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what type of process generated the array or is it completely unknown?

Comment: @Tpofofn I have no clue. I believe it to be a graph output.

Answer (score 1):

There's the great site [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), which has many known patterns in store. All you need to do is feed some portion of the numbers.